# Gradle sync failed: Could not find method defaultConfig()

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

In the first instance my problem was Cause 1: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

but this has escalated since then and now my gradle is broken.
this is the error I am getting:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\stackstorage\android projecten\Converter\build.gradle' line: 26

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Converter'.
> Could not find method defaultConfig() for arguments [build_7komq7i2k7pl5720grjx3kada$_run_closure2@b894d83] on root project 'Converter' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 0s
Could not find method defaultConfig() for arguments [build_7komq7i2k7pl5720grjx3kada$_run_closure2@b894d83] on root project 'Converter' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
Open File
```

event log:

```
12:13   Gradle sync started with IDEA sync

12:13   Gradle sync failed: Could not find method defaultConfig() for arguments [build_7komq7i2k7pl5720grjx3kada$_run_closure2@55d7744a] on root project 'Converter' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (287 ms)

12:13   NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN

12:13   Gradle sync started with IDEA sync

12:13   Gradle sync failed: Could not find method defaultConfig() for arguments [build_7komq7i2k7pl5720grjx3kada$_run_closure2@b894d83] on root project 'Converter' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (230 ms)

12:13   NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN
```

I am unsure what code I need to post for this to get helped but I've seen people posting their build.gradle and gradle.properties, so i'll post mine.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app's APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true
# Kotlin code style for this project: "official" or "obsolete":
kotlin.code.style=official
```

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help. I kinda messed up here.

Comment: Post app level build.gradle as well. It might be any issue in that gradle file because defaultConfig{ } method is there.

Comment: where do i find app level build.gradle?

Answer (score 1):

Check your **app> build.gradle** file. there will be **defaultConfig()** tag like this

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myApp"// your appId
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move defaultConfig{} from gradle project to build.gradle's app module inside android tag.

Should be similar to this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I have copied your android tag and put my own defaultconfig in it like in your code. but I am unable to run it because my run/debug configuration says that its module isnt specified. so now what?

Comment: try just move your defaultConfig with your values to app gradle's without changing any value you had before.  If there is any error, IDE should say what's missing.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with app gradle's?

Comment: I have added a picture where you can see the diferent build.gradle with android's project view

Comment: I didnt even have that file, so i took an old copy i had from this project, copied the main dir from this one into that one and now i'm back to my initial error

Comment: You can try, File -> Invalidate Caches and restart & try to delete .gradle & .idea in your main folder and then, new  -> import project -> your project. Sorry I can't help you more. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have solved the problem. it was a color i set for a vector in a menu i had (the initial error). Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

In android studio, go to your project. Make sure you are in the view mode "Android". Just like this image:
[Should be like this in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkZqp.png)
Go to Gradle-Scripts -> build.gradle (module:app) and make sure it is composed similarly to this:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

    android {


        compileSdkVersion 29
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "your app id"
            minSdkVersion 23
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }


    dependencies {
    //your dependencies
    }
```